# Concise XML from EntityObject through WCF?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, rest, xml-serialization

I'm rather new to WCF and the Entity Framework, so bear with me.

I'm passing objects generated by the Entity Framework through a WCF service, and I want to be able to access said objects with both SOAP and REST. What I have currently works, but the outputted XML seems far more bloated than it needs to be. Here's an example response from a REST call:

http://www.nodarkthings.com/misc/movies.xml

Previously when I tried this using LINQ to SQL (that is, passing my L2S objects through the WCF service and getting them with a REST call) I had very concise responses that contained primarily property tags and their values. In other words, there were no EntityKey, EntitySet, etc. tags.

Is there a way to achieve this using the Entity Framework through WCF?

Edit: Also, it seems that methods passing/returning variables derived from EntityObjects will not work in the WCF Test Client. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution was to use POCO objects and pass these instead. You can find a series of articles on this approach starting with:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx

There's also an excellent template for generating these classes automatically, which you can find here: 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313

**Update:** Rather than using basic POCO objects, I've found that using Self-Tracking Entities (or STEs) is a better approach. STEs are essentially POCO objects with a small tracker built into each object. This makes it *much* easier when you go to update your objects/database.